# Why the CSS properties is not picking while browser width decreased?

Tags: html, css

I have the `CSS` file where I have media screen for the responsive design. But the problem is everything is working fine but the `CSS`  properties is not taking by the table id= "phone". 
Below is my **code**. Tell me what might be the problem.

```css
@media  only screen and (max-width: 760px),
(min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)  {
     /* table properties for phone  */
    table#phone thead, tbody, th, td, tr {
        display: block;
    }

    /* table properties for datepicker */
    table:(.ui-datepicker) table, thead, tbody, th, td, tr {
    display:none;
    }
```

Comment: In which element you want to apply? Only to table with id phone ?

Answer (score 0):

Because your code targeting all the `td, th, tr, tbody`. It should be specific like below.

```
 @media  only screen and (max-width: 760px),
(min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)  {
 /* table properties for phone  */
table#phone thead,
table#phone tbody,
table#phone th,
table#phone td,
table#phone tr {
    display: block;
}

/* table properties for datepicker */
table.ui-datepicker table,
table.ui-datepicker thead,
table.ui-datepicker tbody,
table.ui-datepicker th,
table.ui-datepicker td,
table.ui-datepicker tr {
display:none;
}
```

Comment: i am using this code for all table by removing #phone but its not working .So is there any way to declare the above code for all the table not for "phone" only and for "datepicker" its seperate.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```css
    @media  only screen and (max-width: 760px), 
            (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)  {
        
        /* table properties for phone  */
        table.phone thead,
        table.phone tbody,
        table.phone th,
        table.phone td,
        table.phone tr {
          display: block;
        }

        /* table properties for datepicker */
        table:(.ui-datepicker) table,
        table:(.ui-datepicker) thead,
        table:(.ui-datepicker) tbody,
        table:(.ui-datepicker) th,
        table:(.ui-datepicker) td,
        table:(.ui-datepicker) tr {
          display:none;
        }
    }
```

Here's more info on CSS Specificity: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try like following.

```
table#phone thead,table#phone tbody,table#phone th,table#phone td,table#phone tr
{
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: @Emiipro i am using this code for all table by removing #phone but its not working .So is there any way to declare the above code for all the table not for "phone" only and for "datepicker" its seperate.

Comment: Yes. You can try this. `table, thead, tbody, th, td, tr
{
    display: block;
}`

Comment: And if it is still not working then you may try using `!important` like this. `display: block !important;`

Comment: @Emiipro both approach  is not working .can u tell another way to achieve  this.